# Wrapping text in pads using ncurses. (In C)

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

I've been playing around with ncurses and I've found very little useful information on the net dealing with pads. I understand that pads are a sort of larger window off screen, sections of which can be printed on smaller windows on screen.

I wrote a program to print the context of a pad on screen. The problem is that the program only seems to print "line-to-line" and doesn't wrap around text.

The program's output is something like this:

> abcdefghij
>
> abcdefghij
>
> abcdefghij

But it should be like this:

> abcdefghij
>
> klmnopqrst
>
> uvwxyzabc

In the later case the same line "wraps" around rather than multiple lines being printed.

Can any ncurses gurus tell me how to achieve this wrapping functionality? (I.e: Magic?)

Ask if you need further details, source code of the program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
    WINDOW *pad_ptr;
    int x, y;
    int pad_lines;
    int pad_cols;
    char disp_char;

    initscr();

    pad_lines = LINES + 50;
    pad_cols = COLS + 50;

    pad_ptr = newpad(pad_lines, pad_cols);

    disp_char = 'a';
    for(x = 0; x < pad_lines; x++)
    {
            for(y = 0; y < pad_cols; y++)
            {
                    mvwaddch(pad_ptr, x, y, disp_char);
                    if(disp_char == 'z')
                            disp_char = 'a';
                    else
                            disp_char++;
            }
    }

/* We just filled the pad with letters from the alphabet. */

/* Now we will fill part of the main window with a 10x10 section
 * of the pad.
 * Notice that the text does not wrap around. (Where is 'k'?)
 */

    prefresh(pad_ptr, 0, 0, 3, 3, 9+3, 9+3);
    sleep(3000);

//  prefresh(pad_ptr, LINES + 5, COLS + 7, 5, 5, 21, 19);
//  sleep(4);

    delwin(pad_ptr);

    endwin();

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding the way pads work.

Pads allow you to create a window (possibly larger than the physical screen) and then show a subset of the window. When you display the pad with prefresh you are displaying a view of a subset of the pad. The content is not altered (or wrapped) when you display the subset of the pad.

If you Add the code below to your sample you will see the viewport moving each time you press a key but the content of the pad is not changed.

```
for (x=0; x<10; x++) {
    prefresh(pad_ptr, 0, x, 3, 3, 9+3, 9+3);
    wgetch(pad_ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change pad_lines and pad_cols to 9 and see if you are happier.

Let's say LINES and COLS are 100 on your system.  You are creating a 10+k array in the pad something like:

```
a-z..a-z..a-z..a-k
l-z..a-z..a-z..a-d  
e-z..a-z..a-z..a-o //etc
```

and then your `prefresh()` displays the first 9 columns (of 9 lines) on the screen.