# How do you make RPG-like scrolling text? C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, scroll

I'm a beginner coder making a simple text 'choose your own adventure' game, but I want it to scroll out the text like an [RPG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) instead of just spitting out the text. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library is exactly what you are looking for. It allows you lower access to the terminal text, to produce things like full screen text, like this:

[image: Picture of ncurses terminal window]

A tutorial for how to use it can be found [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/), and you can download version 6.3 [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-6.3.tar.gz).

It is used in many applications, like GNU [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano). A full list of applications using *ncurses* can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Software_that_uses_ncurses).

Comment: Which link is about text scrolling? Also it seems like ncurses does stuff with C not C++.

Comment: @JacobThompson It will work just fine with C++, and I believe that using the `pad` function is required. I think you can use pads, and using the `prefresh` command with different values as the second and third argument, scroll the window. I am not sure, as I am inexperienced in the ways of `ncurses`, but I looked in there links for resources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912889/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-implement-text-scrolling-in-ncurses https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133489/wrapping-text-in-pads-using-ncurses-in-c

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're just supposed to write to a console.

```
std::string str = "Your text";
for(char& current_char : str) {
    std::cout << current_char << std::flush;
    sleep(1000);
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

The `for` loop is going to iterate over each character in the string.
It will then output it to *cout*. `std::flush` is here to force the output to be update without using `std::endl` which would return carriage and we don't want that.

`sleep` will pause for an amount of time in milliseconds, here 1000 milliseconds (1 second). Be careful though; `sleep` is a Windows function. On Linux, use [usleep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/usleep). If you need it to be cross-platform you should probably use the thread sleeping functions or make something yourself with [chrono](https://cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/).

And finally, we use `std::endl` to return carriage and update the output.

Comment: Will I have to do the for loop around every block of std::cout, or do you do it around every std::cout? Also what does the & and : do in the for loop?

Comment: Every time you wanna call `std::cout` you would have to do this. So you would probably make a function that you pass your text to, and call said function instead of std::cout.

And the '&' is here to make `current_char` a reference to the string's character. A "simpler" kind of pointer. That prevents the character from having to be copied which would slow the loop down. Have a quick look at what references are, they are quite useful.